# Миграции в Laravel

Tags: php

Изучаю ларавель. Создаю миграцию, вписываю поля которые надо создать. Потом запускаю миграции, вылезают ошибки, таблица не создаеться. В чем проблема? БД создана. OpenServer.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 <?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateArticlesTable6 extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');   // id INT auto_increment  PRIMARY KEY
            $table->string('name',100); //Varchar, 100
            $table->text('text');   //text
            $table->string('img',255); 
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('articles');
    }
}
```

Comment: По-моему, проблема в миграции с пользователями (о чем написано в ошибке), а не со статьями.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

подозреваю что laravel 5.4 
там в качестве кодировки по умолчанию используется utf8mb4
соответственно если у вас mysql версии ниже 5.7.7
или изменяете длину строк по умолчанию
в AppServiceProvider

```
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

или [вот этот вариант](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_large_prefix)

но я им не пользовался

так же можно посмотреть на [laravel-news](https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-4-key-too-long-error)

Comment: Да, Laravel 5.4. Можете объяснить нубу чуть подробнее как это ,сделать и где прописать что надо.  в    App\Providers вот это:  `<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
 `   а в

Comment: @Djonson А что не ясно ? Иди в класс App\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php, подключай класс  Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema, если нет метода boot() копируй то что дали выше и все.

Comment: Получилось, спасибо. Не могу понять, как здесь благодарить за ответ, подскажите нубу.

Comment: отметьте ответ как верное решение

Comment: как это сделать? нигде не могу найти